# Atmosphere of a hypothetical planet

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, atmospheric-science, planets

A hypothetical planet is 2/3 the radius of earth but has 1g surface gravity. Given the planet has the same surface gravity as earth, the atmospheric pressure would be the same. This would also mean there is less atmosphere in terms of mass on my planet. Would this also mean the atmosphere on my planet has the same scale height ? How high is my planet’s atmosphere compared to Earth's ? What other consequences would there be for my planet's atmosphere due to the planet’s size ?

Comment: This seems to be more suitable for [worldbuilding.se] than here

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the [World building site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Related questions from physics, astronomy, worldbuilding, and space SE: "[What determines the magnitude of the atmospheric scale height of a planet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632480/145491)", "[What are the scale heights of the atmospheres of the Solar System worlds?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/48434/47727)", "[Determining "scale height" for fictitious planet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/83299/98864)", "[Atmospheric scale height, how is it calculated?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17351/49534)".

Comment: Note that escape velocity is reduced by a factor of $\sqrt{2/3}\approx 0.8165$, which makes it easier for atmosphere molecules to escape.

Comment: You can't predict atmospheric height or thickness from the planet's gravity or size. For example, Venus has a much heavier atmosphere than Earth, despite being slightly smaller. You should probably also compare Earth's atmosphere to that of Titan - a moon, not a planet, much smaller than Earth, but with a greater surface atmospheric density than ours.

Comment: Voting to reopen. I have removed the references to D&D, which leaves a perfectly clear *physics* question about the atmosphere on a hypothetical planet.

Comment: _Given the planet has the same surface gravity as earth, the atmospheric pressure would be the same_ Nope. Gravity is not the only factor which contributes to [atmospheric pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure), other factors are also important such as atmospheric gas molar mass as per ideal gas law $ p=\rho {\frac {R}{M}}T$. Temperature at sea level,- if planet is young with a lot of volcanic activities or close to the star, which heats atmosphere more, then certainly pressure will be higher. So, from planet gravity you can't deduce anything about it's atmosphere.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas I think you overcomplicate this, better to calculate only the atmosphere weight above a unit area. With the same surface gravity and the same atmospheric mass above a unit area, also the surface pressure will be the same. Although OP did not mention that he thinks similarly about 1kg of air above all square cm.

Comment: @peterh. No, it's you who oversimplify the problem. OP hasn't specified the temperature at the sea level, nor atmosphere chemical composition, so that molar mass could be deduced, nor gas density. So pressure at the sea level can't be deduced, unless OP specifies more things. You can, of course try to assume bunch of things yourself, but then hypothetical planet would be "doubly hypothetical".

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Yes, these all are important factors in nearly all gas formula. But sometimes things are becoming surprisingly constant, independent from everything. This time, conservation of mass is our friend: if you have 1kg of gas over all $1 cm^2$ of planet surface, then you will have 1 atm pressure. Molar mass, temperature, degrees of freedom, these are all calculated but ultimately will lead to the same result.

Comment: @peterh Not so sure. Gas weight pressure $mg/A$ is not the same factor as ideal gas pressure, because it only accounts for gravity. And $1 kg$ of hot and cold gasses over $1 cm^2$ makes the difference, that's why temperature is accounted in barometric pressure formula (and in ideal gas law too). In addition, you don't know how much $kg$ of gas will be over $1 cm^2$ only by knowing gravity and surface area. It depends on many factors, such as gas production rate by biosphere/planet, how hot atmosphere are,- hotter gases may evaporate into outer-space faster leaving thinner layer in planet, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Atmospheric pressure on a planet tends to scale with gravity since gravity is what allows it to hold particles in, but there's no a priori reason it would have to have Earth's pressure. Venus is roughly Earth's size but has 100 times the pressure.

Density will scale with potential energy, so that $N(h) \sim N_0 e^{- gh}$ where h is the height above the surface and $N_0$ is the density at sea level.

Comment: No mention of temperature.

Comment: @ProfRob ok . . . .

Comment: $gh$ is not dimensionless, so your equation makes no sense. What matters is the ratio of gravitational potential energy to thermal energy $\mu gh/k_BT$.

Comment: So just say the exponent should be that instead of a vague "no mention of temperature"? Or edit it yourself? The question is just asking about how gravitational strength and planet size fit into the question.